# Avoid rounding in new python string formatting

Tags: python, string, format

I want to replace the old string formatting behaviour with the new python string formatting syntax in my scripts, but how to avoid rounding when I deal with floats?

The old version

```
print ('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (0.0,0.9,67.5))
```

yields `00:00:67`

while my (obviously wrong) translation into the new syntax

```
print ('{0:0>2.0f}:{1:0>2.0f}:{2:0>2.0f}'.format(0.0,0.9,67.5))
```

yields `00:01:68`.

How to avoid rounding here and get the old output with the new format syntax?

Comment: Apart from the answer, Check this out too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511612/format-float-as-int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explicitly convert the arguments to `int`s:

```
>>> '{:02}:{:02}:{:02}'.format(int(0.0), int(0.9), int(67.5))
'00:00:67'
```

BTW, you don't need to specify argument index (`{0}`, `{1}`, ..) if you use Python 2.7+, Python 3.1+ (autonumbering).

Comment: Oops, you are explicitly converting to `int` :( I thought that `format` has a way to truncate the decimal part.

Answer (score 2):

The "rules" are simple:

```
'%d' % 7.7         # truncates to 7
'%.0f' % 7.7       # rounds to 8
format(7.7, 'd')   # refuses to convert
format(7.7, '.0f') # rounds to 9
```

To have complete control over the presentation, you can pre-convert the float to an integer.  There are several ways to do that depending on your needs:

```
>>> math.trunc(f) # ignore the fractional part
67
>>> math.floor(f) # round down
67
>>> math.ceil(f)  # round up
68
>>> round(f)      # round nearest
68
```

Comment: `format(7.7, '.0f')` rounds to 8 and not 7